# What‘s mean of *=*gpu in conda/pip install?

Tags: python, pip, conda

What's  means of `*=*gpu` in `conda/pip install`?

See below:

```
conda install deepmd-kit=*=*gpu lammps-dp=*=*gpu
```

Comment: Where did you find this syntax used? That format doesn't seem to be covered in [Anaconda package specification](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/package-spec.html)

Comment: The only usage i know of that uses `=` is when u create a virtual env with `conda create -n <venv name> python=3.6`. In this case, the `=` is used to specify the version of python. It is probably to specify a version or parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax allows you specify the version and build type of the package.

```
conda install <package name>=<version filter>=<build filter>
```

For your case, it installing any version of `deepmd-kit` and `lammps-dp` that are built for GPU.

Here are some other examples:

1. install any version of `deepmd-kit` compatible with the environment:

```
conda install deepmd-kit
```

2. install major release 1, any compatible minor release

```
conda install deepmd-kit=1.*
```

3. install major release 1, minor release 2, any subversion

```
conda install deepmd-kit=1.2.*
```

4. install major exactly version 1.2.1

```
conda install deepmd-kit=1.2.1
```

Adding an additional equal syntax filters by the build string.

5. install major release 1, any compatible minor release, built for python 3.8

```
conda install deepmd-kit=1.*=py38*
```

6. install major release 1, any compatible minor release, built for GPU

```
conda install deepmd-kit=1.*=*gpu
```

7. install major release 1, any compatible minor release, built for python 3.8 and GPU

```
conda install deepmd-kit=1.*=py38*gpu
```